# Identification of Bioluminescent Species in South Carolina Marshlands

Tags: species-identification, marine-biology, bioluminescence

I was in the brackish marshlands in South Carolina and the water was lit with short flashes of greenish bioluminescent light from a species that seemed to be floating in the current.  The lights seemed to be associated with a crackling noise as well but I'm not 100% sure that the light and sound were related as there were so many flashes going off at a given.

When I turned a flashlight on I saw some quarter inch long bugs moving in the water but the light was too bright to confirm that the bioluminescent light was coming from those bugs.

Comment: Do you have a picture?

Comment: Quarter of an inch is quite large but it sounds like bioluminescent plankton. All lumped together by their behavior when we call them "plankton", there is tremendous variety of species of these animals and plants. Unfortunately, I think it might be impossible to identify which species you observed without a clear photograph or a microscopic image from a sample taken.

Comment: We tried to take a movie but it didn't come out.   The lights were just short flashes and a ton of them in the water, but they were spaced out fairly well. The plankton idea is probably correct we were thinking small pistol shrimp (Alpheidae) given the sound, but the light the cavitation produces is not supposed to be visible.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed by a number of locals later on to be a small species of pistol shrimp. It was a pretty cool phenomenon.  Thanks for the help here.